# Type casting and function signature

Tags: javascript, jquery, haxe

I wonder how could i **sign my private function**  *(exemple : function onTweets(datas:RightType):Void )* so i can directly iterate through datas.results without extracting results before my for loop ?

```
private function onTweets(datas:Dynamic):Void {
    var tweets:Array<Tweet> = new Array<Tweet>();
    var results:Hash<Dynamic> = datas.results;
    for (data in  results ) {
        var tweet:Tweet = new Tweet( { from_user: data.from_user , created_at : data.created_at , text : data.text } );
        tweets.push(tweet);
    }
    this._datas = datas ;
    this._tweets = tweets ;
    this._next(tweets);
}
```

Here is how my object looks like in **Chrome** :

[image]

The tweets come from a $.getJSON call.
thanks

Comment: for (data in cast (results, Hash <Dynamic>)) ?

Comment: hi,thanks , i tried that but got a "class casting error" on the console at run time :( ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you casting to Hash, if the results seems to be an Array?

```
private function onTweets(datas:{ results : Array<Dynamic> }):Void {
    var tweets:Array<Tweet> = new Array<Tweet>();
    for (data in datas.results ) {
        var tweet:Tweet = new Tweet( { from_user: data.from_user , created_at : data.created_at , text : data.text } );
        tweets.push(tweet);
    }
    this._datas = datas ;
    this._tweets = tweets ;
    this._next(tweets);
}
```

Is this what you want?

edit:
You can even define a more specific type:

```
typedef TweetData = {
    created_at: String,
    from_user: String,
    from_user_id: Int,
    from_user_id_str: String
};

private function onTweets(datas:{ results:Array<TweetData> }):Void
```